# Issues utilizing xacro properties

Tags: ros-melodic, robot-state-publisher, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**launch file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
    <arg name ="model"/>
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find three_wheel_robot)/urdf/robot.xacro"/>
    <param name="use_gui" value="true"/>
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/>
    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher"/>
    <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args ="" required="true"/>
    
</launch>
```

**xacro file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="macroed" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:property name="width" value="0.2" />
  <xacro:property name="leglen" value="0.6" />
  <xacro:property name="polelen" value="0.2" />
  <xacro:property name="bodylen" value="0.6" />
  <xacro:property name="baselen" value="0.4" />
  <xacro:property name="wheeldiam" value="0.07" />
  <xacro:property name="pi" value="3.1415" />

  <material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0 0 0.8 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="black">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
  </material>

  <material name="white">
    <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
  </material>

  <xacro:macro name="default_inertial" params="mass">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="${mass}" />
      <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0" />
    </inertial>
  </xacro:macro>

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${width}" length="${bodylen}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder radius="${width}" length="${bodylen}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:default_inertial mass="10"/>
  </link>

  <xacro:macro name="wheel" params="prefix suffix reflect">

    <link name="${prefix}_${suffix}_wheel">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${wheeldiam/2}" length="0.1"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="black"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <cylinder radius="${wheeldiam/2}" length="0.1"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <xacro:default_inertial mass="1"/>
    </link>
    <joint name="${prefix}_${suffix}_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
      <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <parent link="${prefix}_base"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_${suffix}_wheel"/>
      <origin xyz="${baselen*reflect/3} 0 -${wheeldiam/2+.05}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>

  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:macro name="leg" params="prefix reflect">
    <link name="${prefix}_leg">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <box size="${leglen} 0.1 0.2"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 -${leglen/2}" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
        <material name="white"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <box size="${leglen} 0.1 0.2"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin xyz="0 0 -${leglen/2}" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0"/>
      </collision>
      <xacro:default_inertial mass="10"/>
    </link>

    <joint name="base_to_${prefix}_leg" type="fixed">
      <parent link="base_link"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_leg"/>
      <origin xyz="0 ${reflect*(width+.02)} 0.25" />
    </joint>

    <link name="${prefix}_base">
      <visual>
        <geometry>
          <box size="${baselen} 0.1 0.1"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="white"/>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <box size="${baselen} 0.1 0.1"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <xacro:default_inertial mass="10"/>
    </link>

    <joint name="${prefix}_base_joint" type="fixed">
      <parent link="${prefix}_leg"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_base"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 ${-leglen}" />
    </joint>
    <xacro:wheel prefix="${prefix}" suffix="front" reflect="1"/>
    <xacro:wheel prefix="${prefix}" suffix="back" reflect="-1"/>
  </xacro:macro>
  <xacro:leg prefix="right" reflect="-1" />
  <xacro:leg prefix="left" reflect="1" />

  <joint name="gripper_extension" type="prismatic">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="gripper_pole"/>
    <limit effort="1000.0" lower="-${width*2-.02}" upper="0" velocity="0.5"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${width-.01} 0 0.2"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="gripper_pole">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${polelen}" radius="0.01"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="${polelen/2} 0 0" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0 "/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="${polelen}" radius="0.01"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin xyz="${polelen/2} 0 0" rpy="0 ${pi/2} 0 "/>
    </collision>
    <xacro:default_inertial mass="0.05"/>
  </link>

  <xacro:macro name="gripper" params="prefix reflect">
    <joint name="${prefix}_gripper_joint" type="revolute">
      <axis xyz="0 0 ${reflect}"/>
      <limit effort="1000.0" lower="0.0" upper="0.548" velocity="0.5"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="${polelen} ${reflect*0.01} 0"/>
      <parent link="gripper_pole"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_gripper"/>
    </joint>
    <link name="${prefix}_gripper">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="${(reflect-1)/2*pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://three_wheel_robot/mesh/l_finger.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://three_wheel_robot/mesh/l_finger.dae"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="${(reflect-1)/2*pi} 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      </collision>
      <xacro:default_inertial mass="0.05"/>
    </link>

    <joint name="${prefix}_tip_joint" type="fixed">
      <parent link="${prefix}_gripper"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_tip"/>
    </joint>
    <link name="${prefix}_tip">
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="${(reflect-1)/2*pi} 0 0" xyz="0.09137 0.00495 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://three_wheel_robot/mesh/l_finger_tip.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://three_wheel_robot/mesh/l_finger_tip.dae"/>
        </geometry>
        <origin rpy="${(reflect-1)/2*pi} 0 0" xyz="0.09137 0.00495 0"/>
      </collision>
      <xacro:default_inertial mass="0.05"/>
    </link>
  </xacro:macro>

  <xacro:gripper prefix="left" reflect="1" />
  <xacro:gripper prefix="right" reflect="-1" />

  <link name="head">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="${width}"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="${width}"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:default_inertial mass="2"/>
  </link>

  <joint name="head_swivel" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="head"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 ${bodylen/2}"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="box">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.08 0.08 0.08"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
      <origin xyz="-0.04 0 0"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.08 0.08 0.08"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <xacro:default_inertial mass="1"/>
  </link>

  <joint name="tobox" type="fixed">
    <parent link="head"/>
    <child link="box"/>
    <origin xyz="${.707*width+0.04} 0 ${.707*width}"/>
  </joint>

</robot>
```

**errors**

```
[ERROR] [1614263672.672957320]: length [${bodylen}] is not a valid float
[ERROR] [1614263672.674347113]: Could not parse visual element for Link [base_link]
[ERROR] [1614263672.674434457]: Unable to parse component [${polelen/2}] to a double (while parsing a vector value)
[ERROR] [1614263672.674469569]: Could not parse visual element for Link [gripper_pole]
[ERROR] [1614263672.674510951]: radius [${width}] is not a valid float
[ERROR] [1614263672.674536954]: Could not parse visual element for Link [head]
[ERROR] [1614263672.674625029]: Unable to parse component [${width-.01}] to a double (while parsing a vector value)
[ERROR] [1614263672.674655343]: Malformed parent origin element for joint [gripper_extension]
[ERROR] [1614263672.674676083]: joint xml is not initialized correctly
[robot_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 12220, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/hn/.ros/log/92f21f62-7776-11eb-92c1-38b1dbc81381/robot_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/hn/.ros/log/92f21f62-7776-11eb-92c1-38b1dbc81381/robot_state_publisher-2*.log
[WARN] [1614263673.100220]: gripper_extension is not fixed, nor continuous, but limits are not specified!
[WARN] [1614263673.105475]: The 'use_gui' parameter was specified, which is deprecated.  We'll attempt to find and run the GUI, but if this fails you should install the 'joint_state_publisher_gui' package instead and run that.  This backwards compatibility option will be removed in Noetic.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372753/issues-utilizing-xacro-properties/) by [hamdi sharaf](https://answers.ros.org/users/58228/hamdi-sharaf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2021-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-02-25**:
@hamdi sharaf in the future please use the `101010` button to format code blocks. I've edited your question and provided a more descriptive title. Best of luck getting your problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are setting the `robot_description` parameter to the contents of your xacro file but it actually needs URDF data, which you use the `xacro` program to generate. The way this is normally done is something like:

`<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find three_wheel_robot)/urdf/robot.xacro'" />`

Using the `command` attribute instead of `textfile` runs the value as a shell command and sets the parameter value to the output of that command.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2021-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0